# ¿Cómo se escriben en contextos con mayúsculas las letras voladas?

Tags: ortografía, abreviaturas, uso-de-mayúsculas

Muchas abreviaturas —sobre todo las que incluyen una vocal o sílaba entera al final— llevan letras voladas.  Por ejemplo, tenemos *M.<sup>a</sup>* por María, abg.<sup>do/a</sup> por *abogado/a*, ser.<sup>mos</sup> por *serenísimos*.

Pero ¿cómo debemos escribirlas en contextos en los que todas las letras van en mayúscula?  Obviamente, hay una tecla con *º* y *ª* pero carecen de formas en mayúscula en Unicode (existe *ᴬ* y *ᴼ* en los bloques fonéticos pero no creo que se las deba usar en textos normales, y tampoco existen equivalentes para todas las letras del alfabeto español).

Por ejemplo, digamos que tenemos que escribir lo siguiente (no tiene mucho sentido pero bueno...):

> La testigo, Madre María del Barrio del Pilar, habló con el abogado Fernández, miembro de las Serenísimas Comisiones del Estado, quien le dio el Visto Bueno para su primer capítulo en el libro sobre la Compañía de Impuestos.

El cual, si quisiésemos abreviar al máximo, se abrevia en:

> La test.<sup>o</sup>, M.<sup>e</sup> M.<sup>a</sup> del B.<sup>o</sup> del Pilar, habló con el abg.<sup>do</sup> F.<sup>dez</sup>, miembro de la Ser.<sup>ma</sup> Com.<sup>ón</sup> del Estado, quien le dio el V.<sup>o</sup> B.<sup>o</sup> para su 1.<sup>er</sup> cap.<sup>o</sup> en el libro sobre la C.<sup>ía</sup> de Imp.<sup>os</sup>

Pero en mayúsculas, ¿cómo debe aparecer? Veo dos opciones:

> **Opción A**
>   LA TEST.<sup>o</sup>, M.<sup>e</sup> M.<sup>a</sup> DEL B.<sup>o</sup> DEL PILAR, HABLÓ CON EL ABG.<sup>do</sup> F.<sup>dez</sup>, MIEMBRO DE LA SER.<sup>ma</sup> COM.<sup>ón</sup> DEL ESTADO, QUIEN LE DIO EL V.<sup>o</sup> B.<sup>o</sup> PARA SU 1.<sup>er</sup> CAP.<sup>o</sup> EN EL LIBRO SOBRE LA C.<sup>ía</sup> DE IMP.<sup>os</sup>

Y luego

> **Opción B**
>   LA TEST.<sup>O</sup>, M.<sup>E</sup> M.<sup>A</sup> DEL B.<sup>O</sup> DEL PILAR, HABLÓ CON EL ABG.<sup>DO</sup> F.<sup>DEZ</sup>, MIEMBRO DE LA SER.<sup>MA</sup> COM.<sup>ÓN</sup> DEL ESTADO, QUIEN LE DIO EL V.<sup>O</sup> B.<sup>O</sup> PARA SU 1.<sup>ER</sup> CAP.<sup>O</sup> EN EL LIBRO SOBRE LA C.<sup>ÍA</sup> DE IMP.<sup>OS</sup>

La segunda me parece mejor, pero veo con muchísima frecuencia el poner (sobre todo) la *a volada* en minúscula cuando las demás letras van en minúscula, pues no sé.

Comment: No encuentro nada al respecto ni en la ortografía y ni en la gramática. He propuesto la pregunta a la RAE en Twitter, a ver qué responden.

Comment: @carlosalejo por eso formulé la pregunta, es curioso que no esté contemplado en la *Ortografía*

Answer (score 5):

Pues una vez consultada a la RAE vía Twitter, su respuesta ha sido [la siguiente](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/829648175564722176):

> Lo normal es que las letras voladas mantengan su forma minúscula en los textos escritos en mayúsculas o versalita.

Así que en principio tu opción A sería la más adecuada. Nótese que la RAE dice "lo normal", así que no habría que descartar totalmente tu opción B, simplemente dicen que la A se da con más frecuencia. Al parecer no hay una regla definida y se limitan a expresar lo que es más corriente.

No he podido encontrar apenas ejemplos por Internet. De hecho, el único que he encontrado es un documento francés que, efectivamente, lo hace como indica la RAE (nótese la abreviatura de "etcétera"):

[image: &ra]

Los siguientes ejemplos no contienen letras voladas (salvo uno, que no acierta a poner el punto en el sitio correcto), de hecho ni siquiera son contextos plenamente formales como puede ser el del documento anterior, pero podrás observar una cierta discrepancia a la hora de emplear mayúsculas o minúsculas en las abreviaturas:

[image: Hermanos1]

[image: Hermanos2]

[image: Hermanos3]

[image: Hermanos4]

[image: Hermanos5]

Answer (score 1):

Buenas.

Yo también lo consulté a la RAE y me ha llegado la respuesta hoy mismo diciendo lo siguiente:

[image]

Entonces, aunque no existe una regla, se recomienda:

> Que las letras voladas mantengan su forma minúscula en los textos escritos en mayúsculas o versalitas.

Un saludo.

Comment: Lo curioso de la respuesta es que en versalitas, sí que ha ido a mayúscula :-)