# ¿Cuál es exactamente la regla para los puntos finales que coinciden con abreviaturas?

Tags: gramática, ortografía, abreviaturas

Buscando información para la pregunta de [las abreviaturas con letras voladas en contextos en mayúscula](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19657/12637), me encuentro en el DPD con [lo siguiente](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=fKODyKTfZD6s0mX7bz):

> En las abreviaturas que llevan letras voladas, el punto se escribe delante de estas: Sr.<sup>a</sup>, 3.<sup>er</sup>. Si una abreviatura coincide con final de oración o de párrafo, el punto de la abreviatura sirve de punto final, de modo que solo se escribirá un punto y no dos.

Sin embargo, estas dos frases parece que se están contradiciendo a sí mismas. En la segunda se afirma que el punto de la abreviatura sirve como punto final. En la primera se afirma que en las abreviaturas con letras voladas el punto se escribe antes que estas. Pero la primera frase acaba con una abreviatura y tiene dos puntos: uno delante de la abreviatura y otro detrás.

¿Es esto correcto? La frase no especifica que las abreviaturas con letras voladas sean una excepción.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El DPD (redactado en 2005), además de ser más antiguo que la última edición de la ortografía (que es de 2010), suele condensar las normas para que ocupen menos espacio. En la última edición de la ortografía podemos consultar [la norma completa](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=hMkzTaCmRDDatAaw):

> Únicamente si el punto abreviativo coincide con el del final de un enunciado, se escribirá un solo punto y no dos [...]. Si una abreviatura con letras voladas va situada al final de un enunciado, no debe omitirse su punto abreviativo, ya que no ocupa la última posición: *Siempre exige que delante de su nombre aparezca la abreviatura D.<sup>a</sup>.*

Comment: ¿Y por tanto diríamos _con otro órdago venidero por la 14.ª._? En [esta noticia](https://elpais.com/deportes/2018/05/31/actualidad/1527789504_014667.html) solamente usan _14ª._ y resulta confuso, supongo que es erróneo.