# ¿Por qué se debe usar un punto en las abreviaturas con números?

Tags: ortografía, abreviaturas, números

Siguiendo con las preguntas sobre abreviaturas, y usando la misma frase que [en la pregunta anterior](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19663/12637):

> En las abreviaturas que llevan letras voladas, el punto se escribe delante de estas: Sr.<sup>a</sup>, 3.<sup>er</sup>.

Entiendo que se deba poner un punto en *Sr.<sup>a</sup>*, dado que "Sr." es la abreviatura de "señor", aunque luego siga una letra volada. Sin embargo, ¿la cifra *3* de qué es abreviatura? Mi tendencia es a escribir *3<sup>er</sup>*, sin punto, dado que un *3* de por sí no es abreviatura de nada. Por tanto, ¿por qué se debe escribir un punto cuando la supuesta abreviatura está escrita con números? ¿Esta norma siempre ha sido así?

Por aclarar un poco más: mi consideración es que la letra volada tras los números no implica una abreviatura, sino un cambio en la forma de pronunciar el número:

> ```
> 51:  Cincuenta y uno  
> 51º: Quincuagésimo primero
> ```

Entendería el punto si se escribiera así: *Quinc.<sup>o</sup> prim.<sup>o</sup>* (por poner un ejemplo forzado).

Comment: También yo leí esta norma hace poquito, creo que en un artículo de la Fundéu, y me llamó mucho la atención. No le veo la lógica por ningún lado.

Comment: The simplest thing is to stop writing the full stops at all. Over the last half a century or so it is what we have done in English and it does not seem to have caused any disasters. Have courage, start a new movement to abolish them.

Comment: Al igual que tú nunca he escrito un punto delante de una letra volada. Al igual que @Gorpik no veo la lógica.

Comment: Creo (sin saber nada con certeza) que la lógica sería usar punto delante de cualquier letra volada, y dado que los número ordinales las empleen, pues también usan los puntos. También, quizás, sería oportuno notar que los números tradicionalmente llevaban puntos antes y después, sean ordinales o cardinales. Así que hablaban de, por ejemplo, en el año .2015. algo ocurrió con .25. personas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La *Ortografía* dice [lo siguiente](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=KnmXkSYCFfBkASif):

> Entre las abreviaturas que incluyen letras voladas forman un grupo especial las que corresponden a los numerales ordinales, que se crean combinando la cifra que representa el número de orden con las terminaciones voladas <sup>a</sup>, <sup>o</sup>, <sup>er</sup>, que corresponden a la palabra numeral abreviada: *1.<sup>o</sup>* por *primero*, *2.<sup>a</sup>* por *segunda* [...].

No explica el motivo, pero preguntada a la RAE en Twitter, me responden ([parte 1](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/829981998282334208), [parte 2](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/829987600953917440)) lo siguiente:

> La abreviatura de ordinales es un tipo especial de las abreviaturas formadas por contracción: por convención se inicia con cifra y se omite todo salvo la última letra, que va volada («3.º»). El punto indica abreviat.

El quid de la respuesta es lo de **"por convención"**. Lo que me hace pensar que guifa tiene razón en su comentario al afirmar que el punto no significa que el número sea una abreviatura, sino que lo que es una abreviatura es la letra volada que le sigue, y por tanto delante de la abreviatura (la letra volada) tiene que ir un punto. Es decir: por convención cualquier expresión que lleve una letra volada al final es una abreviatura y las abreviaturas siempre llevan punto.

Comment: Precisamente me ha venido hace un rato a la cabeza esta pregunta y he pensado justo lo que te contesta la RAE: que la abreviatura no es el número, sino el conjunto con la letra volada. De todos modos, me parece que en este caso no voy a seguir las indicaciones de la RAE. Y, buscando en Google, encuentro 1,4 millones de instancias de *3.º* frente a 80 millones de *3º*, conque parece que el uso actual tiende a la eliminación de ese punto.

Comment: Continuando con el comentario de @Gorpik, es inexplicable que la RAE no reconozca el uso común lleno de sentido común ya que las letras voladas son suficientes para indicar que se trata de una abreviatura.

Comment: (cont.) Es llamativo que la RAE sí siga es uso común cuando éste deforma o empobrece la lengua. Considérense las siguientes dos versiones de una oración. 1) «Hubiera asistido si me hubieras invitado» y 2) «Habría asistido si me hubieras invitado». La última versión es la que se solía enseñar en las escuelas y la que es coherente con el sistema de tiempos verbales. Sin embargo, la 'Gramática de la lengua española' coloca en primer lugar la opción 1 y en segundo lugar la opción 2. La opción 1 en presente: «Asistiera si me invitaras». Opción 2 en presente: «Asistiría si me invitaras».

Comment: (cont.) Pareciera que la RAE tiene pavor a todo lo que se parezca al inglés. Quizá podrían relajarse si tienen en cuenta que el punto no se usa en francés, catalán, holandés... ¿Hay algún otro idioma que use el punto entre el número y letras, voladas o no?